# Script resets data when I entry wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, json

My problem is that script resets all collected values when I entry value that is not in json. I tried to do this with else, while statements, but then it seems that for loop doesn't loop through json. How can I solve this problem?
Array looks like this:

```
arr = [[123, "foo", 143,99],[456, "bar", 99,99],[789, "spam", 100]]
```

There is the full code: https://pastebin.com/xu0tKVbJ

Script:

```
    var total = 0;
    var price = 0;
    var productsJSONList = (("{{products_json}}").replace(/&(l|g|quo)t;/g, function(a,b){
        return {
            l   : '<',
            g   : '>',
            quo : '"'
        }[b];
    }));
    var prod = JSON.parse(productsJSONList);



    document.getElementById('entry').onsubmit = enter;

    function enter() {
        var entry = document.getElementById('newEntry').value;
        for (var i = 0; prod.length; i++) {
            var obj = prod[i];
            if (obj[0].toString() === entry.toString()) {
                price = parseFloat(obj[2]);


                currency = currencyFormat(price);
                document.getElementById('entries').innerHTML += '<tr><td></td><td>' + currency + '</td></tr>';
                total += price;
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = currencyFormat(total);

                document.getElementById('newEntry').value = '';
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    function currencyFormat(number) {
        var currency = parseFloat(number);
        currency = currency.toFixed(2);
        currency = currency + ' zł';
        return currency;
    }
```

Comment: Paste the code here, please.  Off-site links die over time.

Comment: You're submitting the form. You should pass `event` into `enter` and then `event.preventDefault()`. This will stop the form submitting until the time you've completed the validation when you can submit it if you need to.

Comment: Okay I tried to google that, but I can't figure out how to do that and where I need to put that. I'm using javascript only to do that for my django project, so sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you click a submit button inside a form, your browser navigates you to the url in the form's `action` attribute. This makes it possible to submit a form without using ajax and triggers a page reload.

However, in your case, you want to handle the form submission yourself, so you should disable the default behavior. This is as simple as calling `preventDefault` on the event object that is passed to your `onsubmit` handler

```
function enter(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do that before seeing answer, but your explanation of problem is very useful for me. Here is code that works like I want:    document.getElementById('entry').addEventListener('submit', enter);
        function enter(event) {
            event.preventDefault();